# Combine two SQL queries that are different size because a where

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two SQL queries.

In one I search how many cities are in each country and filter all the ones  with less than 6 cities.

In the second one I search how much population is there in the capital and filter all the ones that have less than 500000 inhabitants.

The result that I am looking is searching all the countries with more than 6 cities in the database and less than 500000 inhabitants, because they are different sizes I can't seem to unite them

```
select c.name, count(ci.name) as states_in_country
from country c, city ci
where c.code=ci.country 
group by c.name
having count(ci.name)>5 
;

select c.name, c.capital, ci.population
from country c, city ci
where c.capital=ci.name and ci.population>500000
;
```

I wanted to make it both in the same one like

```
select c.name, count(ci.name) as states_in_country, ci.population
from country c, city ci
where c.code=ci.country and c.capital=ci.name
group by c.name
having count(ci.name)>5 
;
```

But that shows the counter for cities as just one. the capital.

Thanks

Comment: Could you show both country and city tables schema and sample data?

Comment: I'm a bit confused on what is your objective. If you filter per number of inhabitants **in the capital** how would the query show any other city (unless of course they are another capitals) would you please clarify?

Comment: @jorge the end result that i am looking is country, amount of cities in that country, capital of that country, population of capital

but only if cities are more than 5 and population is less than 500000

Comment: @kristech im not sure what you are asking me, but im gonna try to show you what i get

in the first query the result that i get is 
NAME                                STATES_IN_COUNTRY
Italy                                                 54
Ethiopia                                           10


in the second

NAME                                CAPITAL                             POPULATION

Monaco                              Monaco                                    1234
Holy See                            Vatican City                               392

Comment: Also, is your database MySQL or Oracle? you tagged both

Comment: @jorge oracle sql developer, i used the stackoverflow recommendations tag

Comment: Hi there @Tuliodnw did any of the provided answers helped you out? If so, please consider making it (the one worked better for you) as accepted. You do so by clicking on the V icon at the left of chosen answer.

Comment: @jorge, not yet. here is the map from the data base. https://imgur.com/a/Biu2uNo
i tried looking into join inner but have had no luck.

Comment: Hi there, So I good thing to do then is to provide a sample data of your database (just some rows from both tables) and from that sample what would be the result you need. This will help clarify your question a lot and we will be able to answer you more accurately. Take a look at this thread on how to setup a sample data: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/460557

Answer (score 0):

seems that you are lokking for not IN the query you have tried

```
select c.name 
from country 
where c.name NOT IN (
  select c.name
  from country c
  INNER JOIN city ci ON c.code=ci.country 
  group by c.name
  having count(ci.name)>5 
  ;

)  
and NOT IN (
  select c.name
  from country c
  INNER JOIN city ci ON c.capital=ci.name and ci.population>500000
)
```

Answer (score 0):

A join should do the work:

```
SELECT
    c.name,
    count(ci.name AS cities_in_country),
    c.capital,
    ci.population
FROM country
LEFT JOIN city ON c.code = ci.country
WHERE ci.population > 500000
HAVING COUNT(ci.name) > 5;
```

Comment: You are outer joining, because you are also interested in countries that have no cities? But of these zero cities more than five must have more than 50000 inhabitants? Don't outer join when you don't have to. And when you have to, make sure to put join criteria in the `ON` clause, not in `WHERE`. (Your `WHERE`  clause renders your outer join a mere inner join, because outer-joined records have a null population.)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a query that may work. Pay attention to the fact that you mention **population is less than** and you are using on your query `> 500000` which is bigger than. So make sure what you need is actually less.

```
select c.name, 
       cyCapital.name as capital,
       cyCapital.population as capPop,
       count(cy.*) cities
  from country c
         inner join city cy
           on c.code = cy.country
            and cy.population < 500000
         left join city cyCapital
           on c.code = cyCapital.country
           and c.capital = cyCapital.name
group by c.name,
         cyCapital.name as capital,
         cyCapital.population as capPop
having count(cy.*) > 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Countries with more than six cities and less than 500000 inhabitants:

```
select country
from city
group by country
having count(*) > 6 and sum(population) < 500000;
```

Countries with more than six cities and at least one of them with less than 500000 inhabitants:

```
select country
from city
group by country
having count(*) > 6 
  and count(case when population < 500000 then 1 end) > 0;
```

Countries with more than six cities and all of them with less than 500000 inhabitants:

```
select country
from city
group by country
having count(*) > 6 
  and count(case when population >= 500000 then 1 end) = 0;
```

Countries with more than six cities and the capital with less than 500000 inhabitants:

```
select c.code
from country c on ci.country = c.code
join city ci
group by c.code
having count(*) > 6 
  and count(case when c.capital = ci.name and ci.population < 500000 then 1 end) = 1;
```

Well, you get the idea...